# Embarcadero HTML 5 Builder

Tags: html5builder

I have the Builder trial. I have modified the php.ini file to activate mssql.dll, and relocated copies of the infamous ntwdblib.dll. I still cannot connect to MSSQL.

Did anyone have any success in doing this?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question for clarity. What infamous dll? You're talking about the Embarcadero builder trial?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the **[HTML5 Builder documentation for MSSQL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Microsoft_SQL_Server)** first thing.

And make sure you edit *php.ini.template* instead of *php.ini*, since editing the latter will have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about MSSQL, but based on my experience with Embarcadero's latest development tools and mysql databases you should first check for dll versions against database engine versions. If possible install the specified version of db engine that is stated to be supported by the IDE you use. If not you may not be able to use data explorer within the ide, but your application may still connect to database when you deploy.